# how to replace an entire array with another array from fetched data in javascript

Tags: javascript

sorry if my title may sound like a duplicate, but i have not found an answer to what i'm looking for in most of them. Please help!

I'm trying to get some json values using **fetch()** in javascript, But i end up getting aa array inside another array. **Array1(Array2())**

this is the codes

```
var data=[];
fetch('js/contalist.php')
 .then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
 .then(function(myJson) {
var co = myJson
data.unshift(...co);
return co;
});
console.log(data);
```

I expect to have something like this:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "ARISTOT", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
1: {name: "GUEST", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "guest", last_name: ""}
2: {name: "KRBTGT", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
3: {name: "JOHN", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "john", last_name: 
"doe"}
length: 4
```

just one simple array of json data

But i get something like this:

```
[]
0: {name: "ARISTOT", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
1: {name: "GUEST", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "guest", last_name: ""}
2: {name: "KRBTGT", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
3: {name: "JOHN", email: "someone@example.domain", first_name: "john", last_name: 
"doe"}
length: 4
```

i'm i missing something?

Comment: Try `data.concat(co)` instead of `data.unshift(co)`.

Comment: data.concat(co)  returns an empty array

Comment: Unshif doest not accept an array to be added as elements in parent array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Exaple clearly shows what happes when you pass an array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift#Examples

Comment: can you show the ouput using a console.log() ?

Comment: @jo_va,    now i got it working, but intead of having `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "ADMINISTRATOR", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
1: {name: "GUEST", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
2: {name: "KRBTGT", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)` .    i have     `[]
0: {name: "ADMINISTRATOR", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
1: {name: "GUEST", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
2: {name: "KRBTGT", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: ""}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each items of `co` and not the whole `co` array at the beginning of `data`.

Replace this:

```
data.unshift(co); // this adds the co array as the first element of data
```

by this, using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift):

```
data.unshift(...co); // this adds each co item at the beginning of data
```

or by this:

```
data = [...co, ...data]; // spread co items, then spread data into a new array
```

The last solution however, copies the whole array.

Here is a demo of both methods:

```js
const co = [1, 2];
const data = [3, 4, 5];

console.log(...[...co, ...data]); // make a copy (immutable)

data.unshift(...co); // or use unshift (mutates the data array)
console.log(...data);
```

Comment: data.unshift(...co); is perfect sofar, thanks so much., but i'm getting an extra pair of [], i don't know why!

Comment: @Black Berry, where are you getting this extra pair ?